# How to insert data into two table not associated cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

hi how to insert a fixed data in a table in an other file controller, for example i have the add function to add a new order to table ' order', i would like to , when the new order is added, at the same time, a fixed data is added to my other table called Actions, for example table actions contain ID,ID_User,ACTION,DATE,IP
and i would like to add the user ID , the ACTION is fixed by my , like 'ADD' or 'UPDATE' or 'DELETE'....
is that possible in cakephp.
i used this but it doesnt work

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is(array('post'))) {

        $data = $this->request->data;
        $this->loadModel('Historique');
        $article = $this->Historique->newEntity();

        $article->IDUSER = '7';
        $article->ACTIONS = ' article';
        $article->OBJET= 'me';
        $article->IP = ' article';
        $article->DATE = '2020-2-4 04:08:54';


        // die(debug($data));
        if ($this->Role->save($data) and $this->Historique->save($article)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Role enregistré avec succès.', 'flash_success');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Rôle n’a pas pu être enregistré. champ vide ou le nom saisi n\'est pas unique, Veuillez réessayer.', 'flash_error');
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Safe to assume that this is actually Cake 3, not one of the Cake 2 versions you've tagged?

Comment: 1. You've made a Historique entity (though called it `$article`), but you haven't made an entity for the submitted data. You need to do that, you don't just `save` raw data.

Comment: 2. You should probably do those two saves within a [transaction](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/database-basics.html#using-transactions), so that if the second one fails, the former gets rolled back too. I prefer the `transactional` call method, myself. The example linked shows `execute` calls within the transaction, but you can do `save` too.